# Is it possible for the lift force unit vector to be equal to the weight force unit vector?

Tags: lift, drag, weight

I know that the drag force is parallel to the direction of flow, thus equal to the unit vector of velocity. But if you consider a vehicle, when its angle of attack is below the velocity vector from a local vertical local horizontal reference frame, does this mean that the lift vector will be pointing downward too and not up?

Comment: That would be a "spoiler".  Yes, of course negative AoA can produce downwards force.  Tails of many planes do the same (up or down) to control *wing* AoA.  Down force helps hold car on the road.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible for the lift force unit vector...

Be careful in the wording, the lift *unit vector* has by definition a magnitude equal to 1, and by convention positive lift is up (or in certain contexts oriented to the suction side of the airfoil, this is equivalent unless flying inverted).

> when its angle of attack is below the velocity vector from a local vertical local horizontal reference frame, does this mean that the lift vector will be pointing downward too and not up?

In simple terms, your question boils down to: Can lift be negative? Yes lift can be negative by adjusting the [angle of attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle_of_attack) to a negative value.

However the angle of attack is not between the direction of flight (velocity vector) and the wing chord, but between the airflow direction (relative wind) and chord:

[image]

The two notions are only equivalent in certain conditions, like when flying at null or constant vertical speed.

Negative lift is is visible on the curve showing the lift coefficient:

[image]

<sup>Lift and drag coefficients according to angle of attack (α), [source (adapted)](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Graph-of-lift-and-drag-coefficient-versus-angle-of-attack-at-Re-6-x-10-6_fig3_317430315)</sup>

On the left hand side, the orange curve is below x axis, and is negative. This occurs for values of α < -3°. So for values >= -3° lift is positive, and below lift is negative, meaning a small negative angle of attack is not sufficient to orient lift downward.

There are control surfaces naturally developing a negative lift value: Horizontal stabilizers (on many aircraft). They are used to prevent the nose to pitch down due to the center of gravity being forward of the center of lift.

[image]

<sup>Horizontal stabilizers developing a negative lift, [source (adapted)](https://www.grc.nasa.gov/www/k-12/airplane/trim.html)</sup>

In the figure above, lift W is positive. It acts on a point which is aft of the center of gravity CG (by dw distance), this creates a pitching moment, the nose tends to pitch down. Horizontal stabilizers are used to produce a negative lift T. Given the longer arm of T (dt), this small negative lift can counter the pitching moment due to lift W. When the aircraft is trimmed this way the wing generates lift W equal to the sum of weight and T.